# ASP.NET MVC AJAX actionlink injects onclick attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I have a partial view which outputs a list of editors.  Each editor in the list has a delete link, which is called using `@Ajax.actionlink`, like this:

```
if(Model.Any()){
    <ul>
        @foreach (var editor in Model)
        {
            <li>@editor.firstName @editor.lastName, @editor.emailAddress (@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteEditor", "EditorSurface", new { editorId = editor.id }, new AjaxOptions()))</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

I've included `@using System.Web.Optimization;` in my view and am calling the jquery unobtrusive ajax script from my view too:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

The issue is that when I view source, the rendered mark-up for my editor list items is like this:

```
<li>John Smith, johnsmith@example.com (<a href="/umbraco/Surface/EditorSurface/DeleteEditor?editorId=32" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace });">Delete</a>)</li>
```

I was a little disappointed to see the inline JavaScript in the delete links and was hoping for something a little 'cleaner' (possibly data attributes or something?).  It strikes me this is going to be difficult to hook into (to provide confirmation messages etc).

Question is, is this the expected output of AJAX in ASP.NET MVC?  I'm very new to this so not sure if I'm doing something wrong in my implementation.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the markup the `Ajax.*` family of helpers produces. My recommendation in general, and especially in light of the fact that you don't want the `on*` attributes added, is to avoid these helpers like the plague. You'll have much cleaner and maintainable (though slightly more verbose) code handling AJAX yourself, i.e. just add a standard `Html.ActionLink` and then use jQuery to attach an event handler that calls the AJAX. Plus, when something goes wrong, as it almost inevitably does, you have full knowledge and control over the JavaScript that is running, rather than being at the mercy of some opinionated Microsoft dev.